# Running total from array, starting from oldest date

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I ran into another... hitch. I've really been trying to avoid asking this question, but I apparently can't solve it on my own. I'm trying to display an "account register". The examples I've found show the register in descending order by date. I can't see why that wouldn't annoy the heck out of anyone trying to use it. I want to see my most recent transactions at the top, not the bottom.

In that spirit, I'm trying to resolve this issue. I *think* I need to get the data from the database in ascending order and then reverse the array. The problem is in displaying the register.

Since it's displayed as a table, it's obviously going to start with the first row. In this case, the first row needs to be the most recent transaction. Since I can't start building the table from the bottom, the data set needs to be in order before I start building the table.

Everything is well and good. It displays exactly as it should, EXCEPT for the running total. Googling this kind of thing gives me ways to do a running total if you're starting at the beginning of the array, which is easy enough.

So here's the code I have so far. I don't want to do the math in the view.

**Model**

```
    public function get_register($acct_id = NULL) {
    $limit = strtotime("now") + 2592000;
    if ($acct_id == NULL) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
            bdgt_trans.trans_amt,
            bdgt_trans.clr_flag,
            bdgt_trans.memo,
            bdgt_trans.trans_date,
            bdgt_trans.chk_num,
            bdgt_cat.cat_label,
            bdgt_payee.disp_name
            FROM bdgt_acct
            JOIN
            bdgt_trans ON bdgt_trans.bdgt_acct_id = bdgt_acct.id
            JOIN
            bdgt_cat ON bdgt_cat.id = bdgt_trans.bdgt_cat_id
            JOIN
            bdgt_payee ON bdgt_payee.id = bdgt_trans.payee_id
            WHERE
            bdgt_acct.acct_default = 1
            AND
            trans_date <= ?
            ORDER BY
            trans_date
            DESC
        ";
        $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, $limit);
    } else {
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
            bdgt_trans.trans_amt,
            bdgt_trans.clr_flag,
            bdgt_trans.memo,
            bdgt_trans.trans_date,
            bdgt_trans.chk_num,
            bdgt_cat.cat_label,
            bdgt_payee.disp_name
            FROM bdgt_acct
            JOIN
            bdgt_trans ON bdgt_trans.bdgt_acct_id = bdgt_acct.id
            JOIN
            bdgt_cat ON bdgt_cat.id = bdgt_trans.bdgt_cat_id
            JOIN
            bdgt_payee ON bdgt_payee.id = bdgt_trans.payee_id
            WHERE
            bdgt_acct.id = ?
            AND
            trans_date <= ?
            ORDER BY
            trans_date
            DESC
        ";
        $query = $this -> db -> query($sql, array($acct_id, $limit));
    }
    if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() AS $row) {
            $array[] = get_object_vars($row);
        }
        return $array;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function index() {
    $acct_id = $this -> uri -> segment(3);
    $data['acct_balance'] = $this -> base -> account_balance($acct_id);
    $data['register_table'] = $this -> read -> get_register($acct_id);
    $data['accounts'] = $this -> base -> acct_list();
    $sum = 0;

    if (!empty($data['register_table'])) {
        foreach ($data['register_table'] AS $ra) {
            if (current($data['register_table']) == $data['register_table']) {
                $sum = $ra['trans_amt'];
            } else {
                $sum = $sum += $ra['trans_amt'];
            }
            $array[] = array('clr_flag' => $ra['clr_flag'], 'trans_date' => $ra['trans_date'], 'disp_name' => $ra['disp_name'], 'chk_num' => $ra['chk_num'], 'cat_label' => $ra['cat_label'], 'trans_amt' => $ra['trans_amt'], $ra['sum'] = $sum);
        }
        $data['array'] = $array;
    }

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE) {
        $this -> stencil -> paint('finance/view_register', $data);
    } else {
        redirect(base_url() . 'finance/view_register/' . $acct_id);
    }

}
```

**View**

```
                        if (!empty($array)) {
                        foreach ($array AS $rt) {
                            echo '<tr';
                            if ($rt['clr_flag'] == 0) {
                                echo ' class="alert alert-warning"';
                            }
                            echo '><td>' . date("m/d/Y", $rt['trans_date']) . '</td><td>' . $rt['disp_name'] . '</td><td>';
                            if ($rt['chk_num'] == 0) {
                                echo 'N/A';
                            } else {
                                echo $rt['chk_num'];
                            }
                            echo '</td><td>' . $rt['cat_label'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $rt['trans_amt'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $rt['sum'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                            echo $rt['cat_label'] != "Manual Adjustment" ? '
                                <input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            ' : '';
                            echo '<input type="button" value="Edit" onClick="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                  <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary" />';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                    }
```

I've tried to break things down so it's as easy to understand as possible. In the controller, I'm doing $data['array'] = $array; in case I have to manipulate the $array prior to passing it to the view data. If I don't wind up having to do that, I'll just do $data['array'] in the loop.

[EDIT]

In response to Abdulla's comment, I suppose the very simplified version is that yes, I need to get the running sum of trans_amt. The problem:

- The initial "running balance" should be the value of trans_amt if it's the first instance in the array.
- In the next row, trans_amt needs to be added to the current running balance. If it's a negative value, indicating an expense, it will obviously be subtracted. This is easily handled.
- The running balance should, I think, be calculated prior to display since a) I have to start building the table from the top, so the balance should already be determined and b) I don't want to do any calculations in the view layer, it should be handled in the controller or the model (if absolutely necessary or like a hundred times easier than doing it in the controller).

So basically, the resulting output should be something like:

> ```
> | Date       | Payee              | Amount | Balance |
> | 01/03/2000 | Burgers-R-Us       | -5.00  | 120.00  |
> | 01/03/2000 | Check from Grandma | 50.00  | 125.00  |
> | 01/02/2000 | Platinum Gym       | -25.00 | 75.00   |
> | 01/01/2000 | Starting Balance   | 100    | 100.00  |
> ```

Comment: If i simplify your question you nee to get total of this `trans_amt` is it ??

Comment: Updated the question. I think that answers your comment?

Comment: You could build the array in oldest to newest first, adding or subtracting the `trans_amt` from the running balance, and then do an `array_reverse($array)` before you pass it to the view, which would flip it to newest->oldest.

Comment: @Craine appreciate it. Tried that. I meant to include it as a commented line in the code sample, but apparently I forgot. Reversing the array prior to passing it to the view does not give successful results.

Comment: So are you assuming that the starting balance is always going to equal the oldest `trans_amt`? Am I reading that correctly? Do you not have a running balance stored elsewhere in the database that you could pull? I might not be understanding your app fully, but I would think that always starting from 0 or the oldest `trans_amt` wouldn't yield the most useful data.

Comment: I would like to assume that, yes. But when you ask the question, it seems impractical. A balance is a balance and has to be a fixed value, I suppose. It can't be variable based on the data set.

Comment: But this adds the task of ensuring that this value is always accurate based on stored transactions. I'm a tad gun shy about storing static numbers and comparing them to calculated values. Probably what put me down this path to begin with.

Comment: Alright, so you make this entire point moot. There needs to be a stored value for cleared and uncleared balances. Just need to write the code to keep then correct. I suspect this will mean adding another column to the database table.

Comment: @Joe Since you're already storing the transactions, it wouldn't be too tough to run tests against a sample of balances and transactions to ensure that they are correct. From what I can deduce on your table names, I'd add a `balance` column to the `bdgt_acct` table, and then use that as the basis for  the running total calculation. Then you can work in the reverse chronological order you want by *subtracting* the `trans_amt` from the balance, to give you the balance for the next line. I'll update my answer with some pseudo code if you like.

Comment: @Craine Nah, I can handle the code, but I appreciate it. I don't recall what my logic was for determining the starting balance, but it obviously wasn't very good.

Comment: @Craine But if you want to update your answer to include storing the balance in the database, I'll flag it as correct, since I don't have enough rep to display an up vote.

Comment: @Craine I remember why now. Transactions may not always be added to the database in the order that they're made or posted. So updating the balance based on the trans_amt may not always be feasible. But that's obviously the way it's going to have to go, somehow. I'll figure that part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 1

Add a column to the database to store the current balance value, then operate on that in the reverse chronological order you want. Start with the stored balance as the value for the `Balance` column in row 1 of your table, then *subtract* the `trans_amt` value from the stored balance and use that value in the next row. Loop through all your rows and you should be set.

### Original Answer

You could build your table in chronological (oldest -> newest) order and then do an [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) in the controller before passing it to the view to get your desired reverse chronological (newest -> oldest) order.

In your **Model** you need to change the select statement to ascending order:

```sql
...
        ORDER BY
        trans_date
        ASC
...
```

And in your **Controller**, call the `array_reverse()` method before passing it off:

```php
public function index() {
    $acct_id = $this -> uri -> segment(3);
    $data['acct_balance'] = $this -> base -> account_balance($acct_id);
    $data['register_table'] = $this -> read -> get_register($acct_id);
    $data['accounts'] = $this -> base -> acct_list();
    $sum = 0;

    if (!empty($data['register_table'])) {
        foreach ($data['register_table'] AS $ra) {
            if (current($data['register_table']) == $data['register_table']) {
                $sum = $ra['trans_amt'];
            } else {
                $sum = $sum + $ra['trans_amt'];
            }
            $array[] = array('clr_flag' => $ra['clr_flag'], 'trans_date' => $ra['trans_date'], 'disp_name' => $ra['disp_name'], 'chk_num' => $ra['chk_num'], 'cat_label' => $ra['cat_label'], 'trans_amt' => $ra['trans_amt'], $ra['sum'] = $sum);
        }
        $data['array'] = array_reverse($array); // <- Perform an array reverse here to flip the order
    }

    if ($this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE) {
        $this -> stencil -> paint('finance/view_register', $data);
    } else {
        redirect(base_url() . 'finance/view_register/' . $acct_id);
    }

}
```

Also, although directly unrelated to the question, you may consider renaming your `$sum` variable to `$balance` or `$running_bal` for readability's sake, but your program, your choice.

Comment: No consideration was given to the naming of that variable. It isn't so much readability as it is a reserved words thing. As it stands, it's a placeholder. But since I've no interest in distributing the project at this time, it really doesn't matter what I call it. I'll look at your answer in more detail tomorrow.